# Optimising canvas tile map drawing

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

My current program requires drawing literally tens of thousands rectangles in a canvas. These rectangles are either grey or red, depending on what they represent. Currently it takes about 5 seconds to draw 100.000 of those rectangles, while the preceding calculations only take less than 100ms. Gladly I'd like to optimise this drawing part of the program, because I feel like I'm missing a major part in optimisation here.

My current drawing code is as follows:

```
function colourRect(i) {
    // Those calculations are for the exact coordinates of the squares in the map
    ctx.rect(((1 + (i - 1) * 12) - settingsWidth * 12 * parseInt((i - 1) / settingsWidth)), (1 + (parseInt((i - 1 / settingsStart) / settingsWidth) * 12) - (parseInt((settingsStart - 1 / settingsStart) / settingsWidth) * 12)), 10, 10);
}

canvas = document.getElementById("map");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
var i = 0;
ctx.fillStyle = "#CCC";
while(i <= parseInt(settingsEnd)) {
    if($.inArray(i, grey) == -1) { colourRect(i); }
    i = i + 1;
}
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();
var i = 0;
ctx.fillStyle = "#900";
while(i <= parseInt(settingsEnd)) {
    if($.inArray(i, grey) != -1) { colourRect(i); }
    i = i + 1;
}
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

Edit note: Colour swapping corrected to happen only twice in total.
Edit note 2: Correct small mistake in array naming (there's only one array, not two)

Comment: You’re calling `parseInt` in a loop; probably don’t do that. Use `.indexOf` instead of `$.inArray`. Set `fillStyle` as little as possible (i.e. once, before each loop). Use `(x | 0)` to cast to integer, not `parseInt(x)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Avoid changing the color, it is costy.
2) Shouldn't you be rather iterating grey and red and testing their values against 0 and settingsEnd ?? Anyway i optimized the processing by using sorted arrays.
3) *if* you simplify the grid to be a simple 12px spaced grid of 10 px squares, you can simplify the drawing by having the canvas do the math for you (translate + scale by 12).

The code below should be faster, notice i change only twice the fillStyle :

```
function fillRect(i) {
       ctx.fillRect(((1 + (i - 1) * 12) - settingsWidth * 12 * Math.floor((i - 1) / settingsWidth)), (1 + (Math.floor((i - 1 / settingsStart) / settingsWidth) * 12) - (Math.floor((settingsStart - 1 / settingsStart) / settingsWidth) * 12)), 10, 10);
}

function drawThings() { 
  var i = 0, j=0;
  settingsEnd = parseInt(settingsEnd);

  ctx.fillStyle = "#CCCCCC"; 
  i=0; 
  if (greyNeedSort) {
      grey.sort(); 
      greyNeedSort = false ;    }
  j=0;
  while(i <= settingsEnd) {
     while(j<grey.length && grey[j]<i) {j++} // find j, a grey index >= i
     if (j<grey.length && grey[j]==i) { fillRect(i); } // draw if found a grey value == i
     else (if j== grey.length-1) break; // exit if no more grey available
     i++;                                               
  }

  ctx.fillStyle = "#990000";   
  i=0; 
  if (redNeedSort) {
     red.sort();  
     redNeedSort = false;    }
  j=0;
  while(i <= settingsEnd) {
       while(j<red.length && red[j]<i) {j++}
       if (j<red.length && red[j]==i) { fillRect(i); }
       else (if j== grey.length-1) break;  // exit if no more red available
       i++;                                             } 
}
```

Edit :
1) This code does just *two* color swap, when the code of the question or the other answer does change much more often.
2) in your code you draw all grey in ascending order, so you even better doing :

```
 if (greyNeedSort) {
     grey.sort(); 
     greyNeedSort = false ;    }
 // just iterate : 
 for (i =0; i<grey.length; i++ ) if (i< settingsEnd) fillRect(i);
```

(same for red).

3) You can have the canvas doing the math for you you simplify you fillRect, it becomes :

```
function fillRect(i) {
       ctx.fillRect(i, i, 0.8, 0.8);
}
```

And you change the drawing method by :

```
function drawThings() { 
  ctx.save();
  ctx.scale(12, 12);
  ctx.translate(0.2, 0.2); // top-left margin

  /// same code ...

  ctx.restore();
}
```

Comment: 1. I corrected that part.
2. What do you mean? You must know that the order in which they are being drawn is important. The fact that I seperated them into two seperate checks, one for red and one for grey, is because it would be more efficient to only set the colours once.
3. Isn't that what I'm theoretically doing now?

Comment: 1. See the updated post. Thanks for the suggestion.
2. I have just one array, and that is called "grey", and that array is always numerically ascending. If a number is not in the grey array, it is automatically red. Sorry if I don't correctly reply to your suggestion.
3. Testing my current method against "ctx.fillRect(1, 1, 10, 10);" doesn't affect the drawing time, from which I can conclude that these calculations take up nearly no time at all.
Also, how does this method wrap? The current code makes sure that, once the horizontal end of the canvas has been reached, it starts at a new row.

Comment: 1. You're welcome (upvote maybe ;-)) 2) the algorithm i suggest should do just like yours, just faster (it iterates only once the two arrays). 3. Not sure you shouldn't rather reduce the tile size but ok if that suits you.

Comment: 1. I'm so noob that I don't even have enough reputation to upvote you. Sorry ^^'
2. And suddenly I get what you're saying! Instead of iterating over all numbers in which the values in the grey array could be, you iterate over only the grey array! But again, after implementing it there are no faster drawing times.
3. Reducing the tile size to 5px instead of 12px does, again, not affect the drawing time.

Thanks for your time and suggestions!

Comment: Well, darn. I just found out that the file I had been optimising was not the file it was using. I'll edit this comment once I've optimised the correct one. Sorry!

Comment: I can't edit my old comment.
I've put all your suggestions in the CORRECT file this time, and the drawing time is now barely 300ms. That means it's now 17 times as fast as before! A million times thanks! I'd definitely upvote your suggestions if only I had enough reputation!

Comment: Wow, 17 times that was worth the effort ! Glad i could help !

Answer (score 0):

Some tips to optimize code:

- Don' use libraries (e.g. jQuery). [Vanilla-js](http://vanilla-js.com/) is much faster.
- Avoid operations in loop conditions. Instead, save the result in a variable before the loop.
- `parseInt` is slow and, in most cases, there are alternatives:

  - `Number` or [unary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_%28.2B%29) (`+`) to convert to numbers.
  - Bitwise OR operator with 0 (`|0`) or `Math.trunc` to truncate to integer.

Also when you iterate from one number to another one, step by step, you can use `for` loops instead of `while` loops.

Then, this should be faster:

```
canvas = document.getElementById("map");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var loopEnd = settingsEnd | 0;

ctx.beginPath();
for(var i=0; i <= loopEnd; ++i) {
    if(!~grey.indexOf(i)) { colourRect(i, "#CCCCCC"); }
}
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();
for(var i=0; i <= loopEnd; ++i) {
    if(~red.indexOf(i)) { colourRect(i, "#990000"); }
}
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

Comment: I rewrote significant parts of the code to remove all traces of jQuery, and carried through all other suggestions you made, but the time needed to draw the whole canvas remains around 5000ms.